# Read content of RAR files using C#

Tags: c#, stream, rar

Is there any way to read the content of a RAR file (support for multi-file RAR is a must)?

I don't want to extract the content to the disk, just read it like a stream.

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737/net-library-to-unzip-zip-and-rar-files

Comment: He just want to unpack i want to read the content like a stream....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Low level lib to work with 7z.dll (supports rar archives, incliding multi-part, works with .net streams):

[C# (.net) interface for 7-Zip archive dlls](http://dev.nomad-net.info/articles/sevenzipinterface)

And more high-level lib based on the first one:

[SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Install NUnrar from nuget

```
RarArchive file = RarArchive.Open("rar file path");//@"C:\test.rar"
                    foreach (RarArchiveEntry rarFile in file.Entries)
                    {
                        string path = "extracted file path";//@"C:\"
                        rarFile.WriteToDirectory(path);

                    }
```

Comment: OP explicitly said they did not want to write to disk

Answer (score 1):

[Chilkat Rar library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/rar-dotnet.asp)

More specific: [link](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/rar_list.asp)

Comment: Nope. All the examples I looked at was extract to disk.

Comment: That does not read it like a stream is just reads the content file names and puts them in a text box

Answer (score 1):

My unrar project, http://nunrar.codeplex.com/ aims to be very .NETty and has streaming support.  If you need something else, please suggest or give me a patch.

Comment: This is what i am using currently! thanks alot for a great product!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is using including the rar command-line executable as application ressource and call it via System.Diagnostics.Process.

You may want to redirect the input/output stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly access files stored in *uncompressed* rar files, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039227/whats-the-file-structure-of-a-rar-file-compressed-in-store-mode/5265578#5265578) might be of use.

> [ReScene](http://rescene.info/) is a project for recreating
>   rar archives from the extracted files.
>   You need a .srr file for this. The
>   source code is available. You may want
>   to take a look at *RarStream.cs*.