# how to download multiple files from database in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

This is code for downloading single file. I need to download  multiple files on single click in a zip folder on local machine

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
    byte[] bytes;
    string fileName, contentType;
    string constr =      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select Name, Data, ContentType from tblFiles where Id=@Id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                bytes = (byte[])sdr["Data"];
                contentType = sdr["ContentType"].ToString();
                fileName = sdr["Name"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = contentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush(); 
    Response.End();
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: single sql command ?

Comment: What upload code is doing here?

Comment: i am using this upload code for uploading multiple files but i am able to download single file from database but i want to download all files on single click

Comment: hiii anirudh thank you for reply single sql command like select data from tblfiles where id ='1';

Comment: why don't you try `select id,data from tblfiles`?

Comment: ya shreesha but iam strucked at downloading multiple files

Comment: you can't download multiple files with response.end() usage. However, you can zip multiple files into a zip and download it.

Comment: check this [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Download-multiple-files-as-Zip-Archive-File-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984590/download-multiple-files-as-zip-in-net)

Comment: thank you shreesha but i want to download files from data base not from path

Answer (score 0):

This  is solution for downloading multiple files . [Multiple File Download using Zip](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Download-multiple-files-as-Zip-Archive-File-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)